# jQuery data table not working in Salesforce lightning component

Tags: datatables, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to add a jQuery data table in Salesforce lightning component. Here is the code. It is not loading at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css'
                        ,'//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'
                        ,'//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
                        ,'//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'
                        ,'//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js'
                        ,'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js'
                        ,'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js'
                        ,'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js'
                        ,'//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js'
                        ,'//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js')}"
            afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterscriptsLoaded}"/>



<table id="showContacts" class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">

                <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-text-title--caps">

                  <span class="slds-truncate" title="EID">EID</span>  

               </th>

               <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-text-title--caps">

                  <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</span>

               </th>
          </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td scope="row">
             <div class="text-wrap">10887738</div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate  text-wrap" title="Adam Will"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Adam, Will</a></div>
         </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


({
afterscriptsLoaded : function(component,event,helper){
    j$('[id$="showStudents"]').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "260px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "dom": 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                        'copy',
                        {extend: 'csv',title: 'Criteria export'},
                        {extend: 'excel',title: 'Criteria export'},
                        {extend: 'pdf',title: 'Criteria export'},
                        'print'
            ]
        } );
},


})
```

My question is about how to show this table on lightning component in Salesforce? Whenever I load the page I see a blank page.

Note: I am showing a sample table.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, and in any other situation what you're doing would work fine, but you'll be banging your head off the wall for a fair while before you get DataTables to work in Lightning - if you ever manage it at all. You're running into Lightning LockerService Security issues. This is an interesting article you might want to look at: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kENGIA2

Comment: You cannot load JS and CSS using cdn Instead Put all these Libraries as static Resource and access it